# ability to view browser view for html file from vim

Tags: vim, html

Is there a plugin / program / key binding that will let me preview html files that I am editing in vim in a browser?

Background: I have abandoned traditional full-feature editors and IDE's (of which I was once a big fan!).  As time has gone by I've realized that most of the skills and knowledge isn't transferable.  So now I stick with vim, tmux and the like.  btw I need high visibility so I need panes not tabs.

I'm not looking for the best tool.  Any one would do.  Maybe it can be done with a key binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Love the idea!

Here's a simple keybinding you can insert into your `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <C-p> :!google-chrome %<CR>
```

Replace `google-chrome` with your favorite browser. This allows you to preview the file you're working on if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> in normal mode.

The only caveat is that this will open a new browser tab each time you ask it to preview the file.

[From OP: I ended up using:

```
nnoremap <C-g> :!google-chrome %<CR> " browser preview with ctrl-p
nnoremap <C-f> :!firefox %<CR> " browser preview with ctrl-o
nnoremap <C-c> :!chromium-browser %<CR> " browser preview with ctrl-c
```

]

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> had previous uses (folding and moving to the bottom) but I wasn't using them so this is ok. Added these at the bottom of the .vimrc file.

Comment: +1 what about different browsers - different key for each?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant You can extend this _ad infinitum_, of course. Make it `<C-g>` for Chrom(e|ium), `<C-f>` for Firefox, and so on...

Comment: ha, yup, that's exactly what I tried, `f` and `g`.  Working well!

Comment: note `chromium-browser` name for chromium

Comment: I think my " comments are possibly invalid btw - but that has the side-effect of eliminating the prompt which gets tiresome.  Call it a beneficial bug :)